# passing in multiple checks as variable arguments in Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I would like to have the ability to pass in checks to a method that makes a gatling post. I am having some issue doing so. I tried using a few different types on the checks but had no luck. I would like to have something like the below on a "page" object that would be used elsewhere in the app. I think I briefly saw there are other types of checks beyond status based checks. I would like the method to be flexible enough to handle such things if possible.

```
protected val commonChecks = Seq(status.not(404),status.not(503))
def login(checks:HttpCheck = commonChecks) = {
  exec(http("post login")
    .post("/login")
    .headers(someheader)
    .formParam("login", "${userName}")
    .formParam("password", "${password}")
    .check(commonChecks) //.check(commonChecks: _*) don't work
  )

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you explicit the type of `commonChecks`:

```scala
protected val commonChecks: Seq[HttpCheck] = Seq(status.not(404),status.not(503))
def login(checks:HttpCheck = commonChecks) = {
  exec(http("post login")
    .post("/login")
    .headers(someheader)
    .formParam("login", "${userName}")
    .formParam("password", "${password}")
    .check(commonChecks: _*)

  )
```

`IntelliJ` seems to infer the following type otherwise:
`Seq[CheckBuilder[HttpCheck, Response, Response, Int] with SaveAs[HttpCheck, Response, Response, Int]]` which causes the compilation error.

Comment: I inferred from what intellij inferred lol. That works like a charm! only problem I have now is this solution does not seem to work with the checkIf() method. Marking as answered as it will get me the mvp I need. If you have any thoughts on how to get that to work with a checkIf() clause I would appreaciate it. Thank you for the help